# Signed message valid only for a specific smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, signature, ecrecover

Is it possible to create a smart contract A and a signed message for which the signature would be valid only if it's signed by the expected Ethereum account **and** the signature check happens in that specific smart contract A?

The naive approach would be to include the address of the verifying smart contract A in the message and then compare that it is equal to `this.address`. However another contract B can be deployed, replacing `this.address` with the actual value of the verifying smart contract A (or even ignore that additional check completely).

Using a nonce avoid "replaying" a signature in the contract A but doesn't prevent contract B from using the signature and verify that it was signed by the expected Ethereum account, similarly it can simply ignore that nonce.

Comment: I don't see any problem with contract B using the signature. Contract shouldn't be able to modify contract A storage.

Comment: But what If the goal is to prevent contract B from reusing the signature? For example if you have some custom logic that you want to be executed when a valid signature gets verified.

Comment: Who is validates the signature? If contract A validates the signature you have to include A address in the signed message, you obtain the sender address from the signature and the message. Contract B cannot modify the signature, also cannot validate it. Contract B can skip the verification but then any contract can skip it in the end they don't need the signature. You should be concerned that the signature received by A is valid and cannot be reused and you should be fine. In case of doubts hire an audit for the contract/protocol.